# How to I check whether a file already contains the text I want to append?

Tags: python-3.x, append

I am currently working on a project. So I want to read all the *.pdf files in a directory, extract their text and append it to a text file. So far so good. I was able to do this, yeah.

Now the problem: if I am reading the same directory again, it appends the same files again. Is there a way to check whether the extracted text is already in the file and thus, skip the whole thing?

My code for this looks like this right now (I created the directory variable already):

`

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        print(file)

        #parse data from file
        file_data = parser.from_file(file)

        #get files text content
        text = file_data['content']
        #print(type(text))
        print("len ", len(text))
        #print(text)

        #save to textfile
        f = open("test2.txt", "a+", encoding = 'utf-8')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()


    else:
        continue
```

`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to extract all the pdf's content into one txt file? @rassar's answer suggests so.

Comment: that is what I did already. Now, since I am using append for this to read all contents into one txt file, I want to filter out all the texts I already used. Thus, with each run through, no text that was originally appended to the text file is appended again

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is load the file contents and check if the file is within the file:

```
if text in open("test2.txt"):
    # write here
else:
    # text is already in file, don't write
```

However, this is very inefficient. A better way is to create a file with the filenames that you have already written, and check that:

(at the beginning of your code):

```
files = open("files.txt").readlines()
```

(before `parser.from_file(file)`):

```
if file in files:
   continue # don't read or write
```

(after `f.close()`):

```
files.append(file)
```

(after the whole loop has finished)

```
with open("files.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(files))
```

Putting it all together:

```
files = open("files.txt").readlines()

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if file in files:
            continue # don't read or write
        print(file)

        #parse data from file
        file_data = parser.from_file(file)

        #get files text content
        text = file_data['content']
        #print(type(text))
        print("len ", len(text))
        #print(text)

        #save to textfile
        f = open("test2.txt", "a+", encoding = 'utf-8')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
        files.append(file)
    else:
        continue

with open("files.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(files))
```

Note that you need to create a file named `files.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say, but I still don't understand what I need to do. So I create another file at the beginning but within the for-loop. But what am I doing with the if-statement, where do I place it?

Comment: thanks for editing. So I guess I put it together correctly. However, it now gives me an error message that the file does not exist (so files.txt), in what mode am I opening the file?

Comment: Well you should create the file before you run the program. Or you could do `if not os.path.exists("files.txt"): open("files.txt", "w")` to ensure that the file exists at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Also, the last lines should be opening the file in mode "a", not mode "w" - see update.

Comment: thanks for our reply. However, the test2 file still appends all the files over and over again (so the content of all the pdf-files). It is not working for me here.